# How to handle encoded and decoded version of the same c# class

Tags: c#, inner-classes, api-design, clean-architecture, hashids

**Scenario**

I am working on updating my .NET API to encode all database key fields so that the sequential key is not exposed to the end user. I'm using [hashids.org](https://hashids.org/) for this and have built helper methods to quickly decode/encode properties in my automapper mapping. However, there are multiple versions of the API and only the most current version should be updated with this functionality, which means that I can't simply overwrite my existing classes. I've implemented a few solutions that work, but they all have a bad code smell that I'm hoping to clear up.

**Solutions**

I am currently performing the encoding at the controller layer. I can see the merits of doing this at the data access layer as well, but feel there is more risk of leaks/missed conversions at that layer, especially since the API has many different data sources. Plus, hiding keys is an issue with the outside world, for which the controller is the gatekeeper, so it feels appropriate there.

The application currently has the following model pattern, which cannot be changed: Model (model that exists in DB) > ValueObject (service model, VO) > DTO (API model).

**(1) Initial attempt**

Below is an example of a class that needs to support an encoded and decoded state, where `Utils.Encode()` and `Utils.Decode()` are helper methods that will convert the field between int and string using Hashids.

```
//EquipmentDTO.cs
public class EquipmentDTO //encoded class
{
  public string Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class EquipmentUnencodedDTO //decoded class
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}

//Automapper.cs
CreateMap<EquipmentUnencodedDTO, EquipmentDTO>()
  .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Utils.Encode(src.Id)));

CreateMap<EquipmentDTO, EquipmentUnencodedDTO>()
  .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Utils.Decode(src.Id)));

CreateMap<EquipmentVO, EquipmentDTO>() //mapping from service model to controller model
  .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Utils.Encode(src.Id)));
CreateMap<EquipmentDTO, EquipmentVO>()
  .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Utils.Decode(src.Id)));

CreateMap<Equipment, EquipmentVO>() //mapping from DB model to service model
  .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
```

- I chose to make the existing `EquipmentDTO` the encoded version
  because I want this to become the new standard, which would
  eventually lead to the deprecation and removal of
  `EquipmentUnencodedDTO` as the old controllers eventually get
  updated.
- I chose to *not* copy `CreateMap<EquipmentVO, EquipmentDTO>` for `CreateMap<EquipmentVO, EquipmentUnencodedDTO>` (and the reverse) because
  it would lead to a lot of duplication in the AutoMapper file, which
  is already huge (though maybe this isn't a real problem?)
- I do not like this solution because in my old controllers, the mapping is now confusing. In a POST, for example, the unencoded input DTO has to be converted to the service model via: `Mapper.Map<EquipmentVO>(Mapper.Map<EquipmentDTO>(unencodedEquipmentInput))` which is super ugly.

  - That being said, this is supposedly a temporary problem, so is this a real problem?
  - This problem would go away if I created `CreateMap<EquipmentVO, EquipmentUnencodedDTO>`
- I do not like this solution because my classes have a lot of duplicated fields that are not changing between the encoded and decoded versions

**(2) Second Attempt**

The two bullet points above led me to refactor to this:

```
public class EquipmentDTO
{
  public string Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public Decoded Decode(){
    return Mapper.Map<Decoded>(this);
  }
  public class Decoded: EquipmentDTO {
    public new int Id {get; set;}
    public EquipmentDTO Encode(){
      return Mapper.Map<EquipmentDTO>(this);
    }
  }
}

// Automappers are the same, except EquipmentUnencodedDTO is now EquipmentDTO.Decoded
```

- I like how simple it is to switch between encoded and decoded states now, reducing my double mapping above to: `Mapper.Map<EquipmentVO>(unencodedEquipmentInput.Encode());`
- I like the nested class because it codifies the relationship between the two classes and also does a better job at identifying which fields get encoded/decoded
- I think this smells a lot worse

**(3) Next Attempt**

My next attempt was to add in the missing mappings for the decoded class to the service model and to undo the changes from attempt #2. This created a ton of duplicated mapping code, I'm still stuck with duplicated properties in both classes without a clear indication to which fields get decoded/encoded, and it all feels much more cumbersome than necessary.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Why not just use a GUID for the primary keys?

Comment: 1) Adding a new GUID field/changing the PK to GUIDs in the data sources would be a much more impactful change and would always be an issue to address when adding new datasources, which is done regularly. Since the API is the only layer that cares, I feel the encoding should be done there. 2) Part of the idea was to use the existing Id fields so that the frontends would be minimally impacted (would only need to change the property type, where required)

Comment: Another alternative, of course, would be to keep the data models untouched and create new data models that support the encoding. This plus duplicating the mappings would no longer require me to change the old controllers. This would add a bunch of duplicated code, though, and the issues I had with #3 would remain

Comment: Be careful in using the `new` operator in the second attempt for overloading the `Id` property because now you have two `Id` properties in the same object.

Comment: First, I would do this in the business layer, not in the ASP.NET controllers, and the DAL should never know or care about this functionality. I would have a service with an interface which generally allowed for converting/mapping an entity ID to another, ephemeral identifier. This way you can DI-in something like Redis for production and a Dictionary<int, Guid> for testing. I wouldn't try to put this functionality in my "stack" or class hierarchy..

Comment: @BriansaysReinstateMonica thats an interesting approach. I have a lot of questions about what this sort of implementation would look like. Could you post an answer based on the simple class above?

Comment: @TabsNotSpaces I will try to get that done - trying to knock stuff out before the end of day and holiday tomorrow, but I should be able to at least give you solid outlines.

Comment: @TabsNotSpaces Have you EquipmentDTO and EquipmentUnencodedDTO coded in the same file?

Comment: @DavideCastronovo currently yes, if for no other reason than to show that they are related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of playing around, I ended up going the route of not using automapper and only having a single DTO for both the encoded/unencoded states by using custom getters/setters to control what value would be returned based on a readonly property `isEncoded`.

My problem with automapper and having multiple DTOs was that there was too much duplication and way too much code to write to add a new decodable DTO. Also, there were too many ways to break the relationship between encodedDTO and unencodedDTO, especially since there are other developers on the team (not to mention future hires) who could forget to create the encoded DTO or to create a mapping to properly encode or decode the ID values.

While I still have separate util methods to perform the encoding of a value, I moved all of the automapper "logic" into a base class `EncodableDTO`, which would allow a user to run `Decode()` or `Encode()` on a DTO to toggle its encoded state, including the encoded state for all of its encodable properties via reflection. Having a DTO inherit `EncodableDTO` also serves as a clear indicator to developers to what's going on, while custom getters/setters clearly indicate what I'm trying to do for specific fields.

Here's a sample:

```
public class EquipmentDTO: EncodableDTO
{
  private int id;
  public string Id {
    get
    {
      return GetIdValue(id);
    }
    set
    {
      id = SetIdValue(value);
    }
  }

  public List<PartDTO> Parts {get; set;}

  public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class PartDTO: EncodableDTO
{
  private int id;
  public string Id {
    get
    {
      return GetIdValue(id);
    }
    set
    {
      id = SetIdValue(value);
    }
  }

  public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class EncodableDTO
{
    public EncodableDTO()
    {
        // encode models by default
        isEncoded = true;
    }

    public bool isEncoded { get; private set; }

    public void Decode()
    {
        isEncoded = false;
        RunEncodableMethodOnProperties(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    public void Encode()
    {
        isEncoded = true;
        RunEncodableMethodOnProperties(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    protected string GetIdValue(int id)
    {
        return isEncoded ? Utils.EncodeParam(id) : id.ToString();
    }

    // TryParseInt() is a custom string extension method that does an int.TryParse and outputs the parameter if the string is not an int
    protected int SetIdValue(string id)
    {
        // check to see if the input is an encoded value, otherwise try to parse it.
        // the added logic to test if the 'id' is an encoded value allows the inheriting DTO to be received both in
        // unencoded and encoded forms (unencoded/encoded http request) and still populate the correct numerical value for the ID
        return id.TryParseInt(-1) == -1 ? Utils.DecodeParam(id) : id.TryParseInt(-1);
    }

    private void RunEncodableMethodOnProperties(string methodName)
    {
        var self = this;
        var selfType = self.GetType();
        // Loop through properties and check to see if any of them should be encoded/decoded
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in selfType.GetProperties())
        {
            var test = property;
            // if the property is a list, check the children to see if they are decodable
            if (property is IList || (
                    property.PropertyType.IsGenericType
                    && (property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)
                    || property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))
                    )
                )
            {
                var propertyInstance = (IList)property.GetValue(self);
                if (propertyInstance == null || propertyInstance.Count == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                foreach (object childInstance in propertyInstance)
                {
                    CheckIfObjectEncodable(childInstance, methodName);
                }
                continue;
            }

            CheckIfObjectEncodable(property.GetValue(self), methodName);
        }
    }

    private void CheckIfObjectEncodable(object instance, string methodName)
    {
        if (instance != null && instance.GetType().BaseType == typeof(EncodableDTO))
        {
            // child instance is encodable. Run the same decode/encode method we're running now on the child
            var method = instance.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
            method.Invoke(instance, new object[] { });
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative to `RunEncodableMethodOnProperties()` was the explicitly decode/encode child properties in the inheriting class:

```
public class EquipmentDTO: EncodableDTO
{
  private int id;
  public string Id {
    get
    {
      return GetIdValue(id);
    }
    set
    {
      id = SetIdValue(value);
    }
  }

  public List<PartDTO> Parts {get; set;}

  public string Name {get; set;}

  public new void Decode() {
    base.Decode();
    // explicitly decode child properties
    Parts.ForEach(p => p.Decode());
  }
}
```

I chose not to do the above because it created more work for DTO creators to have to remember to explicitly add (1) the override method, and (2) any new decodable properties to the override method. That being said, I'm sure I'm taking some sort of a performance hit by looping through every class of my class' properties and its children, so in time I may have to migrate towards this solution instead.

Regardless of the method I chose to decode/encode properties, here was the end result in the controllers:

```
// Sample controller method that does not support encoded output
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddEquipment([FromBody] EquipmentDTO equipment)
{
    // EquipmentDTO is 'isEncoded=true' by default
    equipment.Decode();
    // send automapper the interger IDs (stored in a string)
    var serviceModel = Mapper.Map<EquipmentVO>(equipment);
    var addedServiceModel = myService.AddEquipment(serviceModel);
    var resultValue = Mapper.Map<EquipmentDTO>(addedServiceModel);
    resultValue.Decode();
    return Created("", resultValue);
}


// automapper
CreateMap<EquipmentVO, EquipmentDTO>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<Equipment, EquipmentVO>();
```

While I don't think its the cleanest solution, it hides a lot of the necessary logic to make encoding/decoding work with the least amount of work for future developers

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those answers that doesn't really answer your question directly, but is a different kind of approach to the problem at hand. Based on my comment above.

I would not try to bake in a "hardcoded" transformation, or make the aliasing some intrinsic part of object lifecycle. The idea here is that the transformation of identifiers should be obvious, explicit, and pluggable.

Let's start with an interface:

```
public interface IObscuredIDProvider
{
    public string GetObscuredID(int id);
    public void SetObscuredID(int id, string obscuredID);
}
```

Then, for our testing, a very simple mapper that just returns the int as a string. Your production version can be backed by the hashids.org project or whatever you like:

```
public class NonObscuredIDProvider : IObscuredIDProvider
{
    public string GetObscuredID(int id)
    {
        return id.ToString();
    }

    public void SetObscuredID(int id, string obscuredID)
    {
        // noop
    }
}
```

You'll need to inject the instance of IObscuredIDProvider into whatever layer transforms your "outside/untrusted" data into "trusted/domain" data. This is the place where you will assign the entity IDs from the obscured version to the internal version, and vice versa.

Does that make sense? Hopefully, this is a much more simple to understand and implement solution than baking in a complex, nested transformation....

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesnt this still require I have two classes, one with an int ID and one with a string? From what I can see this just replaces the AutoMapper mapping. The overall flow would still be: API controller receives obscured request > inject and run GetUnobscuredId() and send unobscured class to service layer to interact with DAL > send unobscured response from service layer back to controller > GetObscuredID() and send obscured class to user. Injecting this into the service layer instead would lead to duplicated methods there to choose which type of response to send

Comment: currently, the layer that transforms the untrusted into trusted data is the controller layer, which will send a 500 error if an obscured field cannot be properly decoded

Comment: Sorry I was on vacation. As for multiple classes - your models are your own business, but you tagged this clean-architecture so I assumed you already had multiple models for external vs internal data.

If you are happy with your controllers being the translation boundary, then you can do all of the translations there.